# Why Use Spring Boot with Docker?

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I'm quite new in docker, and i'm wondering that when using spring-boot, we can easily build, ship and deploy the application with maven or gradle plugin; and we can easily add Load Balance feature. So, what is the main reason to use docker in this case? Is containerized really needed in everywhere? Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers helps you to get the software to run reliably when moved from one computing environment to another. Docker consists of an entire runtime environment: your application and all its dependencies, libraries and other binaries and configuration files needed for its execution. 
It also simplifies your deployment process, reducing a hell lot of mess to just one file.

Once you are done with your code, you can simply build and push the image on docker hub. All you need to do now on other systems is to pull the image and run container. It will take care of all the dependencies and everything.